# Second monitor and graphics card (AMD) not detected in Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, multiple-monitors

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows on my Dell Inspiron-5537. The system has switchable graphics - Intel and AMD Radeon 8850M.e

Ubuntu is unable to detect AMD graphics card whereas both are being detected in windows.

Output of `lshw -c video`:

```
description: VGA compatible controller    
product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller   
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

My second screen is also not detected in Ubuntu, while it is in Windows.

Output of `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma
for output default Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768,
maximum 1366 x 768 default connected 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm   
1366x768        0.0*
```

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: It may sound stupid but have you checked the cable connection itself? Check the cable, graphics card and monitor for bent pins and visible damage. It may also help to test the cable in a different computer. Hope it helps :)